# Silverlight layout - one panel at a time

Tags: c#, silverlight, panel

In silverlight, what's the best way to have a bunch of containers filled with controls and be able to display just one of the containers at a time that is also MVVM pattern friendly. I remember there is something in Winforms to do something like that but I was wondering if there is anything in silverlight or toolkit?

```
    -------------------------------------------
   |                     View                 |
   |
   |    Containers:
   | 
   |     -----   -----   -----   -----
   |     |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
   |     |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
   |     -----   -----   -----   -----
   |    
   |               ^
   |               |
   |            currently
   |             active              
   |------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: can you post a mock up of what you want?

Comment: you don't mean a TabControl do you?

Comment: @Phil No, Tabs is not what I'm looking for. I have a set of options on the right and based on which option gets picket, I want to display that container and it's controls while others are hidden. Exactly like the [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are lots of ways of achieving what you want.

A styled TabControl is one way.

This would be another:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding Panel1Visibility}">
        ... contents
    </Grid>
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding Panel2Visibility}">
        ... contents            
    </Grid>
    ... etc
</Grid>
```

You would have a number of overlapped elements, here Grids but they could be anything. Bind the Visibility to individual Visibility properties.
Or have one VisibilityProperty and a converter, something like

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding VisiblePanelNo, 
          Converter={StaticResource PanelVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}">

    </Grid>
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding VisiblePanelNo, 
          Converter={StaticResource PanelVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}">
    </Grid>
    ... etc
</Grid>
```